# Structured data for chord progression

Tags: json-ld, microdata, structured-data, rdfa

I want to add structured data for chord progression.

```
    [Chorus]
F                          C
  Welcome to the Hotel California.
       E7                           
Such a lovely place, (such a lovely 
               Am
place), such a lovely face
```

Can I use any property from [MusicComposition](https://schema.org/MusicComposition)? or any other type.

Comment: A bit tricky. Using `@MusicComposition` is similar to defining a book, author and genre. So the 'book' with title "Hotel California" is authored by the Eagles. The next bit is the tricky part. Text (lyrics) is "ordered" as in any `@CreativeWork`. You want to link a word/phrase to another `@Type` - let's call it `@Sound`. Now you use `@Class` to define `@Sound` (i.e. musical notes) as an extension to schema.org. Then you need to create an `@ItemList` that sequences the words/phrases **and** links the item to your new `@Class`. The `@ItemList` is now your musical score.